# Image scaling approach

Tags: android

I want to show 4 images in  2 x 2 grid format on the screen. Images are sourced from google image search and images are square of 200 X 200

This is my approach to scale them. RelativeLayout with 4 nested RelativeLayout and each layout has imageView in it. and this is how I get screen width to scale images.  Setting internal layoutparams height and width to screenWidth/2 and then scaling images.

this is what I am doing to get the image height and width for particular screen. e.g if screen width is 550 then my image size would be 275 x 275.

```
public static int getOptionWidth(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return metrics.widthPixels;
}

optionWidth = (getOptionWidth(context) / 2)
```

This is for unscaled bitmap

```
public static Bitmap resourceDecoder(byte[] imgBytes, int destWidth, int destHeight) {
    Options options = new Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length, options);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;


    float srcAspect = (float) srcWidth / (float) srcHeight;
    float dstAspect = (float) dstWidth / (float) dstHeight;

        if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
            options.inSampleSize = srcHeight / dstHeight;
        } else {
            options.inSampleSize = srcWidth / dstWidth;
        }
    Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length, options);

    return unscaledBitmap;
}
```

This will be my destination width and height because I need images in square. I have implemented basic method to get source rectangle (getSrcRect) and get destination rectangle (getDstRect)

```
Rect srcRect = getSrcRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(), dstWidth, dstHeight);
Rect dstRect = getDstRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(), dstWidth, dstHeight);
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstRect.width(), dstRect.height(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(unscaledBitmap, srcRect, dstRect, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

return scaledBitmap;
```

This is working fine and results are coming as expected (tested on hdpi, xhdpi and mdpi). But now I am confused as I am no using dxtopx or pxTodX conversion. Am I missing something? though results are as expected I am little worried about the approach. I don't know should I use pxToDx or vice-versa. If I do how does it affect my result and how should I use these.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry about that...please let me know where I am confusing or what part I should edit for better understanding of the question.

Comment: "dxtopx" confused me. Also, your question would be better if you could summarise your problem at the beginning. Don't expect people to read all the text. They will only read it if they think they can help you, after reading the first few lines.

Also, please rewrite the title of the question. One should know what your problem is directly from the title.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use PX to DP conversion for this, because you already set all of your size variables relative to screen width by using getOptionWidth(context).